# Change the content of web page without changing URL

Tags: php, html

I want to make a simple website where a user can enter their name. But I have no idea how I can do this.

Here is what I want.

In my `index.php`, there will be an `input` which allows the user to type their name in. After the user click a button, I want the user to stay in `index.php` but with different contents.
I can do the website which textfield and button. But I don't know what should I do after the user clicks the button.

Don't get what I mean?
For example, this is the Facebook login page.
[image: Source: Google]

After logged in,

[image: Source: Google]

We are still at the same page(index.php) but the content changed. I know how to make websites, but I don't know how to change the content without changing URL(e.g. www.example.com/index.php?u=blah, I only want www.example.com/index.php)

Can anyone provide me an example/idea about how do I make this? Thanks in advanced.
Sorry for my bad English.

EDIT: Sorry for my bad English. Actually I mean, same URL but different content. I googled, I think `cookie` is the best solution.

Comment: You have to do this with Javascript. PHP runs on the server when the page refreshes.

Comment: You will want to use `POST` other than `GET`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PHP to do this as well it is what I do for all of my websites this is just an idea not sure if it is exactly what you are looking for or not but here is a link to my current site if you would like to see it live. be sure to check the url as you click the links at the top of the site. http://www.thedecoy.net

So inside your index.php page you would have your basic html code for the site including the css and images or anything else you use on the site that you want to display on all sites then inside of lets say you content div tag you could do this type of php code.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 
function open_page($string){
    if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/", $string)){
        $string = $string;
    }else{ 
        $string = "";
    }
    return $string;
}
$page = open_page($_GET['page']);
if ($page){
    $file = "pages/".$page.".php";
if (file_exists($file)){
    $pagename = $page;
}else{
    $pagename = "404";
}
include("pages/".$pagename.".php");
}else{
    echo 'Anything you want displayed in the content of your main page would go here';
}
?>
```

You would make a directory called "pages" in your root folder where the index.php file is and then inside this you could create other pages such as about.php, contact.php ect I am sure you get the point, In these files you would only put the content you would want displayed so you would not need all the html head body or anything just what you want in the content div itself.

Let say you wanted to link users visiting your site to the contact.php file you would simply call on the link like so.

```
<a href="index.php?page=contact">Contact</a>
```

which will keep the index.php loaded but change the content to the contact.php information.
The code is a bit sloppy and pulled from my site itself so you may have to work with some things.

Put a 404.php page in the pages folder this will be called if a page is not found so a visitor will see this page if they enter a link that does not exist.

Not sure if I left anything out but please feel free to ask if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX:

> AJAX allows web pages to be updated asynchronously by exchanging small amounts of data with the server behind the scenes. This means that it is possible to update parts of a web page, without reloading the whole page.

I think it's of little use to give here a tutorial on AJAX but you can read [w3school's AJAX tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).
If you understand the basics I'd suggest to use jQuery, a javascript library, which is simpler than pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX for content update without reloading the webpage.

JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var track_load = 0; //total loaded record group(s)
    var loading  = false; //to prevents multipal ajax loads
    var total_groups = <?php echo $total_groups; ?>; //total record group(s)

    $('#results').load("autoload_process.php", {'group_no':track_load}, function() {track_load++;}); //load first group

    $(window).scroll(function() { //detect page scroll

        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())  //user scrolled to bottom of the page?
        {

            if(track_load <= total_groups && loading==false) //there's more data to load
            {
                loading = true; //prevent further ajax loading
                $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image

                //load data from the server using a HTTP POST request
                $.post('autoload_process.php',{'group_no': track_load}, function(data){

                    $("#results").append(data); //append received data into the element

                    //hide loading image
                    $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received

                    track_load++; //loaded group increment
                    loading = false; 

                }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?

                    alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
                    $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image
                    loading = false;

                });

            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<ol id="results"></ol>
<div class="animation_image" style="display:none" align="center"><img src="ajax-loader.gif">    </div>
```

You can find the full tutorial [here](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/auto-load-records-on-page-scroll).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX for it. At first, create a page for collecting form data and then load another submit page using AJAX in your index page. You can check https://github.com/jobayerccj/Simple-Admin-Panel-using-PDO-AJAX, I have created an admin panel using AJAX where I have loaded internal page using AJAX without changing link.

Comment: Yes, I have checked it, you can check my links, after logged in, when anyone try to browse different pages, it will change internal contents, but has not changed url.