# hide php page name in url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have created a site with php and is working fine.I need to hide page urls like for example server.com/login/login.php(which is main page) should be seen as server.com/index

Other files like server.com/login/sqlserver.php,server.com/login/oracle.php,
server.com/login/mysql.php all should be visible like server.com/index.No page names should come.Please suggest how to do it.

I have seen editing the .htaccess file but it says only file extension be removed .I dont want other user to see any file names.

I am using XAMP 7.1

Comment: You could create directories and put the PHP files in there named `index.php` so `example.com/login.php` would become `example.com/login/index.php`. Otherwise you can use a routing framework, of which are a lot out there.

Comment: Create SPA! Or visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696301/change-the-content-of-web-page-without-changing-url)

Comment: How do you expect browsers to ask the server for different pages if you want the URL for all the different pages to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same by using .htaccess.
Check the URL-[htaccess](https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners)

Comment: [htaccess example](https://www.brontobytes.com/knowledgebase/149/htaccess-RewriteRule-Examples.htm)

Comment: htaccess format isnt working.I need to rename a file say login/mysql_create_newdb.php in folder login.I have created the htaccess file in folder C:\xampp\htdocs\login.I have added the rule
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^/mysql1.php mysql_create_newdb.php
When it sees mysql_create_newdb.php it should show mysql1.php but the website isnt showing